# How to edit the admin photo?

Tags: admin

When I go to the admin profile in Wordpress, I don't see a place to edit the photo for the admin.

Would anyone be able to please suggest to me how to navigate to the place where I can change the admin/user profile photo?

Thank you!

Comment: This may help you http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Gravatars